# A simulated TOEFL examination prior to the official one

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

We have the adjective **[mock](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/mock)** in English to describe anything that is going to be real (to me, it has a direct connotation of a simulated thing like an examination). 
For instance, we have a test standard called **[mock test/exam/etc.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/mock-examination)** which as a practice is taken before the official examination! Like: **In IELTS mock test (BE)**

But as you see, it is a sort of BrE term which suits for the IELTS examination.

What do you call such simulated exams for an American standard like TOEFL?

There are some links for **TOEFL mock test**, but as dictionaries mentioned, the word "mock" does not fall into the AE terminology.

Comment: As a native US English speaker, I don't perceive "mock" as exclusively (or even primarily) British. I hear it and use it as "simulated" or "practice" or "not real" all the time.

Comment: "mock" also means imitation as  in "Mock turtle soup" which is an imitaiton of actual turtle soup, and whose name was the subject of wordplay in *Alice in Wonderland*. And i agree with @Chad that "mock" is often used for "simulated"  in US Englaish, althoguh not usually for tests.

Comment: The phrase _mock test_ would be readily understood in American English. (If you don't believe me, simply type the words `Mel Kiper mock draft` into Google and see how many hits you get.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They’re called **practice tests**:

- [IELTS practice test](https://www.ielts.org/en-us/usa/ielts-for-test-takers/ielts-practice-test)
- [TOEFL Practice Test](https://www.4tests.com/toefl)

Practice tests don't have to be done under the same conditions as the real test and often aren't.

You can also call the questions **practice questions**.

(However a practice interview, like for a job, is called a *mock interview*, so you would probably be understood if you said *mock exam*, even in the US. "Mocks" as a noun would be unlikely to be understood though.)

Comment: Thank you @Laurel. But do the "practice" and "mock" mean the same in this sense? How can I differentiate these two?

Comment: In Britain, secondary school pupils take 'practice' or 'mock' examinations before doing the real ones, and this is very often called sitting or doing their 'mocks'.

Comment: @A-friend It says that mock exams are usually taken in school, but practice tests aren't usually done under test conditions. Or at least that's been my experience. I don't remember taking any practice tests under real exam conditions, probably because there was only 45 minutes per class in high school. (I remember taking the PSAT, but I would not consider this a practice test because the results mattered for things like scholarships.)

Comment: UK 'mocks' are done under identical conditions to those of real examinations.